# add icon to drawer react-navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to add an icon to each of the screens in my react-navigation drawer, but the icon doesn't appear.

Here is my code :

```
function Drawer() {
  return (
      <Drawer.Navigator 
       drawerStyle={styles.drawer}
        initialRouteName="Home" 
        drawerPosition='right'
        drawerContentOptions={{
        activeTintColor: 'white',
        inactiveTintColor: 'white',
        itemStyle: { alignItems:'flex-end' },
       }}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="AppTab" component={AppTab1} options={{ headerStyleInterpolator: forFade ,title:"home" ,icon:<Image source={require('./images/icons/plumbing-b.png')} style={styles.drawerActive}/> }} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="News" component={NotificationsScreen} options={{ headerStyleInterpolator: forFade ,title:"new items" icon:<Image source={require('./images/icons/plumbing-b.png')} style={styles.drawerActive}/> }} />
        
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    
  );
}


export function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{
            headerTitleAlign:"center",
            headerRight: ({}) => <HeaderRight />,
            headerLeft: ({}) => <Search />
          }}
          component={Drawer}
          name="Drawer"
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Product" component={Product} options={{title:"product"}} />
        {/*
         * Rest Screens
         */}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

in documentation, adding icon is only mentioned in DrawerItem:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html

Comment: pass custom component

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to simply add drawerIcon in the options

```
<Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home}
        options={{
           title: 'Home',
           drawerIcon: ({focused, size}) => (
              <Ionicons
                 name="md-home"
                 size={size}
                 color={focused ? '#7cc' : '#ccc'}
              />
           ),
        }}
   />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

you can also pass color directly like this

```
...
drawerIcon: ({color, size}) => (
            <Ionicons
               name="md-home" size={size} color={color}
            />
          ),
...
```

here I have used Ionicons for icon, you can use your own icon component or import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'.

Answer (score 13):

Pass `drawerIcon` in your screen's `options`:

```js
options={{
  title: 'Product',
  drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
    <Image
      source={require('./images/icons/plumbing-b.png')}
      style={[focused ? styles.drawerActive : styles.drawerInActive, { height: size, width: size }]}
    />
}}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#drawericon

Answer (score 2):

You can add icons to DrawerItem in DrawerContent component.

in App:

```
function Drawer() {
  return (
      <Drawer.Navigator 
       drawerStyle={styles.drawer}
        initialRouteName="Home" 
        drawerPosition='right'
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: 'white',
          inactiveTintColor: 'white',
          itemStyle: { alignItems:'flex-end' },
        }}
        drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props}/>}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="AppTab" component={AppTab1} options={{ headerStyleInterpolator: forFade ,title:"home" ,style={styles.drawerActive}/> }} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="News" component={NotificationsScreen} options={{ headerStyleInterpolator: forFade ,title:"new items" style={styles.drawerActive}/> }} />

      </Drawer.Navigator>

  );
}
```

in DrawerContent:

```
                  <DrawerItem
                    label='News'
                    onPress={() => 
                      props.navigation.navigate('News')}                                           
                    icon={() =>
                      <Image
                        style={styles.icon}
                        source={require('./images/icons/plumbing-b.png')
                      />
                    }
                  />
```

Answer (score -2):

i configure the Drawer Content using the drawer content: the steps are as follows...
1.Create a drawer with the screens
function DrawerStack({ route, navigation }) {
  return (

```
  drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}

  drawerStyle={{
    backgroundColor: "green",
    alignItems: "center",

    paddingTop: 100
  }}
>
  {/* //it is must to define the screens here */}
  <Drawer.Screen name="Drawer1" component={Drawer1}
  />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Drawer2" component={Drawer2} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

)
}

2.Customise the Drawer Content Using drawerContent:

function DrawerStack({ route, navigation }) {
  return (

```
  drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}

  drawerStyle={{
    backgroundColor: "green",
    alignItems: "center",

    paddingTop: 100
  }}
>
  {/* //it is must to define the screens here */}
  <Drawer.Screen name="Drawer1" component={Drawer1}
  />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Drawer2" component={Drawer2} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

)
}

Comment: Brother you have pasted same code in both the places.